# Date System Used Before ABY in Star Wars

Tags: star-wars

Much like we use B.C.E and A.D, in the Star Wars universe they use B.B.Y and A.B.Y, standing for Before Battle of Yavin and After Battle of Yavin respectively.

But what date system had the galaxy used before the events of Episode 4?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Standard_Calendar

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20070901114255/http://www.holonetnews.com/45/life/13228_2.html

Comment: AIUI, they don't actually use BBY/ABY in-universe: it's just for us to date events relatively.

Comment: @DanielRoseman in the novels, the battle of Yavin is considered to be the "start point" of a new calendar (the caveat being that earlier novels used the Battle of Endor as the start point.)

Comment: Since we are using this as a dup target now, it should be noted that the answer below is Legends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Star Wars* universe has a long history. As you might expect, there have been a number of different dating systems used throughout that time. [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Standard_Calendar) mentions several possible dating epochs. The main alternative that I'm familiar with is the date of the Treaty of Coruscant (3653 BBY), which was used for quite some time, with dates being given BTC and ATC. This is the calendar used in the *Star Wars: The Old Republic* MMO.

[Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Standard_Calendar) also remarks on the *change* in dating system:

> In 25 ABY, the New Republic commissioned the New Republic Historical
>   Council to re-standardize the Galactic Calendar. The
>   historical council chose the Battle of Yavin, instead of the Battle of
>   Endor, calling the former the more significant galactic event. From
>   that point on, the year in which the Battle of Yavin occurred was the
>   epoch used for the dating system.